# Can someone help me understand how to get the I/O relation equations in DES S- boxes

Tags: des, algebraic-attack

I am referring to the equations that have been discussed in Nicolas T. Courtois and Gregory V. Bard's [*Algebraic Cryptanalysis of the Data Encryption Standard*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/402) (in [proceedings of Cryptography and Coding 2007](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-77272-9_10)).

I need a working algorithm or program that will give me all those equations or at least count the number of such equations.

Comment: @SEJPM yes, there are mentions about the low degree i/o relations there. I want to derive all of those equations.

Comment: Have your combed the [Tools for Experimental Algebraic Cryptanalysis](http://www.cryptosystem.net/aes/tools.html) published by the first author?

Comment: yeah i have.. but the program does not work on my pc, each time i execute a command line he program terminates.

Comment: So I guess you'll have to roll your own tool, that's a good way to learn the concepts  (also it looks like the tools now online are much more recent than the paper, thus might not match it). Where are you stuck? Do you understand the first step, which is taking [Appendix 1 of FIPS 46-3](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips46-3/fips46-3.pdf#page=22) and turning each DES S-box into a function $F:(x_1,\dots,x_6)\to(y_1,\dots,y_4)$ expressed as a table of 64 entries of 4 bits each? Next step is turning that into one of the several forms the paper studies; which one is your focus?